# How to search for folder/directory names in search box?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

The standard SharePoint 2016 on-page search boxes find filenames that match search strings. They don't find folder/directory names. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following settings :

1. Make sure the folders are allowed to be searched in the library.
2. Check if you can search the items under the folders.
3. Go to central administration site->search service application->crawl log, make sure the folders has been crawled in the search service application.
4. In the search result page, check if there is any query filter in the search result web part.
   Reset the index in Search service application and then do a full crawl.

Comment: I can search for files under the folders, so the folders aren't excluded from search. Is there a setting in the library settings that determines if folder names can be searched or not? If so, I can't find it.